# refresh contents of mysql driven dropdown list without page refresh

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have a php page with a dropdown list that is populated by a mysql query.

```
$departmentsql="select `department` from `departments` order by department"; 
$resultdepartment=mysql_query($departmentsql); 
$optionsdepartment=""; 
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($resultdepartment)) { 
    $department=$row["department"]; 
    $optionsdepartment.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$department\">".$department; 
}
```

**drop down list code**

```
<SELECT NAME="department" id="department"> 
<OPTION VALUE=0 >
<?=$optionsdepartment?>
</SELECT>
```

I have an option on the page to add a new department, which happens in a drop down list. Once I have added the department? This can be initiated byt he popup page closing or by a refresh link on the page?

Can this be done with PHP or is Javascript required?

Thanks and Regards,
Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use AJAX based queries to achieve this.

Comment: Well, dont have any script. But the whole idea AJAX is to run your queries without refreshing the page. So please learn Ajax. :)